# Is it possible to allow moderators to view, add and edit a snippet

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-snippet

By default, it seems snippets are only accessible to admins in wagtail.

Is there a way to specify a snippet is accessible to moderators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the Wagtail admin (as an administrator), go to Settings -> Groups and select the Moderators group. The snippet types will be listed under "Object permissions"; tick the boxes for the permissions you want to assign.

Comment: Is it any other option to do this in the code?

Comment: @Headmaster Yes, they're standard Django permission records, so they can be created through ORM operations - see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization